# Matrix interpolation in R

Tags: r, function, matrix, interpolation

I have two matrices with dimensions 96x97 and 180x360. I need to find a correlation between them, but for this, they must have the same dimension. Therefore, I want to interpolate a 96x97 matrix and get a 180x360 matrix. With what function can this be done? Help me, please.

Comment: I am going to guess this is more appropriate to be asked on Cross Validated, but I am not flagging yet since I am not sure

Comment: You can code matrix interpolation using functions available in R. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597482/interpolation-with-matrices-in-r).

Comment: These functions are called "scalers" over in videoland, and they can get quite fancy depending on the quality of the scaled "image" you want.  Your problem here is that 180/96 is an ugly number (not an integer), so the interpolation kernel may need to be a bit of a funky shape.

Answer (score 0):

The following packages provide a variety of matrix interpolator functions.  Pick one according to the quality vs. time vs. difficulty of use you like.

pracma
interp
akima

All available at CRAN. Probably some more I have forgotten about.